# I am trying to create a automated script using windows powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to convert one of my queries into an automated script using windows powershell and I'm having issues with certain errors.  Below is an example of the error I am getting:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Declare'.
    Incorrect syntax near '='."
    At C:\Users\vwebster\Documents\Canada\GetCASMGSTD.ps1:60 char:17
    +                 $a = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

What I am trying to do is query the database for the MINIMUM DATE and use that MIN Date to retrieve the data.  Seems to be an issue with my syntax.

Below is the xml query I wrote to query the database.  Can someone hlep me understand what I am doing wrong here ? This is 1 aspect of my query but there are actually a total of about 3 individual queries I am trying to run at once and UNION ALL the results to compile them all into 1 result. Below you will see the full query I am trying to use.  Can someone help me understand how to write this query and get it to work in powershell ?

**FIRST PART OF QUERY**

```
SQLQuery ="
    Declare @monthfrom varchar

    select @monthfrom = CAST(REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(mm,-36,GETDATE()), 120),'-','') AS int)FROM [mediao0].[dbo].[SPSBUYLINESPOT]


select
'DDS-A-CA' as LocalMediaSystemName,
'CA' as SourceCountry,
unit.agency as AgencyCode,
'STARCOM WORLDWIDE' as AgencyName,
unit.client as ClientCode,
client.name as ClientName,
'' as ClientBrandCode,
'' as ClientBrandName,
BUYLINESPOT.product as ProductCode,
product.name as ProductName,
'' as FolioCode,
'' as FolioName,
'' as ParentVendorCode,
'' as ParentVendorName,
unit.station as VendorCode,
'' as VendorName,
unit.estimate as CampaignCode,
' ' as CampaignName,
'' as CampaignType,
unit.media as MediaTypeCode,
'Radio'as MediaTypeName,
'' as SubMediaTypeCode,
'' as SubMediaTypeName,
unit.market as MarketCode,
market.name as MarketName,
'' as ProgramCode,
unit.programname as ProgramName,
unit.daypartcode as Daypart,
'' as TargetAudience,
'' as BuyID,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) as UnitSizeCode,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) UnitSizeName,
'' as DigitalAdFormat,
'' as Position,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120)as ScheduledRunDateStart,
'' as ScheduledRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ScheduledStartTime,
'' as ScheduledEndTime,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.affidavitdatetime,120)as ActualRunDateStart,
'' as ActualRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ActualStartTime,
'UTC-4' as TimeSMGne,
'' as URL,
'' as PlacementID,
'' as PlacementName,
'' as AdServerName,
'' as AdServerSiteID,
'' as AdServerPlacementID,
'' as AdServerCampaignID,
'' as IsBilled,
'' as BillDate,
'' as IsPaid,
'' as PaidDate,
'CAD' as CurrencyCode,
buylinespot.Cost as GrossSpend,
buylinespot.Cost * .85 as NetSpend,
'' as NWMFlag,
'' as VPVH,
'' as HouseholdAvgRating,
'' as CPM,
'' as EstimatedImpressions,
'' as EstimatedGRPs,
'' as ActualImpressions,
'' as ActualGRPs,
'' as GenericField1,
'' as GenericField2,
'' as GenericField3,
'' as GenericField4,
'' as GenericField5,
'' as GenericField6
from mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINE UNIT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINESPOT BUYLINESPOT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSCLIENT client,
mediao0.dbo.SPSPRODUCT product,
mediao0.dbo.SPSMARKET market
WHERE UNIT.AGENCY = BUYLINESPOT.AGENCY
AND UNIT.BuyID = BUYLINESPOT.BuyID
and buylinespot.agency = client.AGENCY
and unit.Media = client.MEDIA
and unit.Client = client.CLIENT
and unit.agency = product.agency
and unit.media = product.media
and unit.client = product.client
and BUYLINESPOT.product = product.product
and unit.agency = market.agency
and unit.media = market.media
and unit.market = market.market
and unit.media = 'r'
and buylinespot.Cost &lt; &gt; 0
and convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120) >= @monthfrom
```

**FULL QUERY**

```
    SQLQuery ="
    Declare @monthfrom varchar

   Select @monthfrom = CAST(REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(mm,-36,GETDATE()),      120),'-','') AS int)FROM [mediao0].[dbo].[SPSBUYLINESPOT]


    select
  'DDS-A-CA' as LocalMediaSystemName,
  'CA' as SourceCountry,
  unit.agency as AgencyCode,
  'STARCOM WORLDWIDE' as AgencyName,
  unit.client as ClientCode,
  client.name as ClientName,
  '' as ClientBrandCode,
  '' as ClientBrandName,
   BUYLINESPOT.product as ProductCode,
  product.name as ProductName,
   '' as FolioCode,
'' as FolioName,
'' as ParentVendorCode,
'' as ParentVendorName,
unit.station as VendorCode,
'' as VendorName,
unit.estimate as CampaignCode,
' ' as CampaignName,
'' as CampaignType,
unit.media as MediaTypeCode,
'Radio'as MediaTypeName,
'' as SubMediaTypeCode,
'' as SubMediaTypeName,
unit.market as MarketCode,
market.name as MarketName,
'' as ProgramCode,
unit.programname as ProgramName,
unit.daypartcode as Daypart,
'' as TargetAudience,
'' as BuyID,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) as UnitSizeCode,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) UnitSizeName,
'' as DigitalAdFormat,
'' as Position,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120)as ScheduledRunDateStart,
'' as ScheduledRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ScheduledStartTime,
'' as ScheduledEndTime,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.affidavitdatetime,120)as ActualRunDateStart,
'' as ActualRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ActualStartTime,
'UTC-4' as TimeSMGne,
'' as URL,
'' as PlacementID,
'' as PlacementName,
'' as AdServerName,
'' as AdServerSiteID,
'' as AdServerPlacementID,
'' as AdServerCampaignID,
'' as IsBilled,
'' as BillDate,
'' as IsPaid,
'' as PaidDate,
'CAD' as CurrencyCode,
buylinespot.Cost as GrossSpend,
buylinespot.Cost * .85 as NetSpend,
'' as NWMFlag,
'' as VPVH,
'' as HouseholdAvgRating,
'' as CPM,
'' as EstimatedImpressions,
'' as EstimatedGRPs,
'' as ActualImpressions,
'' as ActualGRPs,
'' as GenericField1,
'' as GenericField2,
'' as GenericField3,
'' as GenericField4,
'' as GenericField5,
'' as GenericField6
from mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINE UNIT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINESPOT BUYLINESPOT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSCLIENT client,
mediao0.dbo.SPSPRODUCT product,
mediao0.dbo.SPSMARKET market
WHERE UNIT.AGENCY = BUYLINESPOT.AGENCY
AND UNIT.BuyID = BUYLINESPOT.BuyID
and buylinespot.agency = client.AGENCY
and unit.Media = client.MEDIA
and unit.Client = client.CLIENT
and unit.agency = product.agency
and unit.media = product.media
and unit.client = product.client
and BUYLINESPOT.product = product.product
and unit.agency = market.agency
and unit.media = market.media
and unit.market = market.market
and unit.media = 'r'
and buylinespot.Cost &lt; &gt; 0
and convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120) &gt;= @monthfrom


UNION ALL 

select 
'DDS-A-CA' as LocalMediaSystemName,
'CA' as SourceCountry,
unit.agency as AgencyCode,
'STARCOM WORLDWIDE' as AgencyName,
unit.client as ClientCode,
client.name as ClientName,
'' as ClientBrandCode,
'' as ClientBrandName,
BUYLINESPOT.product as ProductCode,
product.name as ProductName,
'' as FolioCode,
'' as FolioName,
'' as ParentVendorCode,
'' as ParentVendorName,
unit.station as VendorCode,
'' as VendorName,
unit.estimate as CampaignCode,
'' as CampaignName,
'' as CampaignType,
unit.media as MediaTypeCode,
'Spot TV' as MediaTypeName,
'' as SubMediaTypeCode,
'' as SubMediaTypeName,
unit.market as MarketCode,
market.name as MarketName,
'' as ProgramCode,
unit.programname as ProgramName,
unit.daypartcode as Daypart,
'' as TargetAudience,
'' as BuyID,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) as UnitSizeCode,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) UnitSizeName,
'' as DigitalAdFormat,
'' as Position,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120)as ScheduledRunDateStart,
'' as ScheduledRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ScheduledStartTime,
'' as ScheduledEndTime,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.affidavitdatetime,120)as ActualRunDateStart,
'' as ActualRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ActualStartTime,
'UTC-4' as TimeSMGne,
'' as URL,
'' as PlacementID,
'' as PlacementName,
'' as AdServerName,
'' as AdServerSiteID,
'' as AdServerPlacementID,
'' as AdServerCampaignID,
'' as IsBilled,
'' as BillDate,
'' as IsPaid,
'' as PaidDate,
'CAD' as CurrencyCode,
buylinespot.Cost as GrossSpend,
buylinespot.Cost * .85 as NetSpend,
'' as NWMFlag,
'' as VPVH,
'' as HouseholdAvgRating,
'' as CPM,
'' as EstimatedImpressions,
'' as EstimatedGRPs,
'' as ActualImpressions,
'' as ActualGRPs,
'' as GenericField1,
'' as GenericField2,
'' as GenericField3,
'' as GenericField4,
'' as GenericField5,
'' as GenericField6
from mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINE UNIT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINESPOT BUYLINESPOT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSCLIENT client,
mediao0.dbo.SPSPRODUCT product,
mediao0.dbo.SPSMARKET market
WHERE UNIT.AGENCY = BUYLINESPOT.AGENCY
AND UNIT.BuyID = BUYLINESPOT.BuyID
and buylinespot.agency = client.AGENCY
and unit.Media = client.MEDIA
and unit.Client = client.CLIENT
and unit.agency = product.agency
and unit.media = product.media
and unit.client = product.client
and BUYLINESPOT.product = product.product
and unit.agency = market.agency
and unit.media = market.media
and unit.market = market.market
and unit.media = 'T'
and buylinespot.Cost &lt; &gt; 0
and convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120) &gt;= @monthfrom



union all

select 
'DDS-A-CA' as LocalMediaSystemName,
'CA' as SourceCountry,
unit.agency as AgencyCode,
'STARCOM WORLDWIDE' as AgencyName,
unit.client as ClientCode,
client.name as ClientName,
'' as ClientBrandCode,
'' as ClientBrandName,
BUYLINESPOT.product as ProductCode,
product.name as ProductName,
'' as FolioCode,
'' as FolioName,
'' as ParentVendorCode,
'' as ParentVendorName,
unit.station as VendorCode,
'' as VendorName,
unit.estimate as CampaignCode,
'' as CampaignName,
'' as CampaignType,
unit.media as MediaTypeCode,
'Network TV' as MediaTypeName,
'' as SubMediaTypeCode,
'' as SubMediaTypeName,
unit.market as MarketCode,
market.name as MarketName,
'' as ProgramCode,
unit.programname as ProgramName,
unit.daypartcode as Daypart,
'' as TargetAudience,
'' as BuyID,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) as UnitSizeCode,
cast(unit.seconds as NCHAR) UnitSizeName,
'' as DigitalAdFormat,
'' as Position,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120)as ScheduledRunDateStart,
'' as ScheduledRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ScheduledStartTime,
'' as ScheduledEndTime,
convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.affidavitdatetime,120)as ActualRunDateStart,
'' as ActualRunDateEnd,
convert ( varchar(8), buylinespot.AffidavitDateTime,108) as ActualStartTime,
'UTC-4' as TimeSMGne,
'' as URL,
'' as PlacementID,
'' as PlacementName,
'' as AdServerName,
'' as AdServerSiteID,
'' as AdServerPlacementID,
'' as AdServerCampaignID,
'' as IsBilled,
'' as BillDate,
'' as IsPaid,
'' as PaidDate,
'CAD' as CurrencyCode,
buylinespot.Cost as GrossSpend,
buylinespot.Cost * .85 as NetSpend,
'' as NWMFlag,
'' as VPVH,
'' as HouseholdAvgRating,
'' as CPM,
'' as EstimatedImpressions,
'' as EstimatedGRPs,
'' as ActualImpressions,
'' as ActualGRPs,
'' as GenericField1,
'' as GenericField2,
'' as GenericField3,
'' as GenericField4,
'' as GenericField5,
'' as GenericField6
from mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINE UNIT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSBUYLINESPOT BUYLINESPOT,
mediao0.dbo.SPSCLIENT client,
mediao0.dbo.SPSPRODUCT product,
mediao0.dbo.SPSMARKET market
WHERE UNIT.AGENCY = BUYLINESPOT.AGENCY
AND UNIT.BuyID = BUYLINESPOT.BuyID
and buylinespot.agency = client.AGENCY
and unit.Media = client.MEDIA
and unit.Client = client.CLIENT
and unit.agency = product.agency
and unit.media = product.media
and unit.client = product.client
and BUYLINESPOT.product = product.product
and unit.agency = market.agency
and unit.media = market.media
and unit.market = market.market
and unit.media = 'n'
and buylinespot.Cost &lt; &gt; 0
and convert(varchar(10), buylinespot.spotdate,120) &gt;= @monthfrom


union all

select 
'DDS-A-CA' as LocalMediaSystemName,
'CA' as SourceCountry,
unit.agency as AgencyCode,
'STARCOM WORLDWIDE' as AgencyName,
unit.client as ClientCode,
client.name as ClientName,
'' as ClientBrandCode,
'' as ClientBrandName,
unit.product as ProductCode,
product.name as ProductName,
'' as FolioCode,
'' as FolioName,
'' as ParentVendorCode,
'' as ParentVendorName,
unit.PUBNUMBER + unit.PUBEDITION + unit.PUBZONE as VendorCode,
pub.name as VendorName,
unit.estimate as CampaignCode,
'' as CampaignName,
'' as CampaignType,
unit.media as MediaTypeCode,
media.medianame as MediaTypeName,
'' as SubMediaTypeCode,
'' as SubMediaTypeName,
'' as MarketCode,
pub.city + ' ' + pub.state as MarketName,
'' as ProgramCode,
'' as ProgramName,
'' as Daypart,
'' as TargetAudience,
'' as BuyID,
'' as UnitSizeCode,
unit.SPACEDESCRIPTION as UnitSizeName,
'' as DigitalAdFormat,
'' as Position,
convert(varchar(10), unit.INSERTIONDATE,120)as ScheduledRunDateStart,
'' as ScheduledRunDateEnd,
'' as ScheduledStartTime,
'' as ScheduledEndTime,
'' as ActualRunDateStart,
'' as ActualRunDateEnd,
'' as ActualStartTime,
'UTC-4' as TimeSMGne,
'' as URL,
'' as PlacementID,
'' as PlacementName,
'' as AdServerName,
'' as AdServerSiteID,
'' as AdServerPlacementID,
'' as AdServerCampaignID,
'' as IsBilled,
'' as BillDate,
'' as IsPaid,
'' as PaidDate,
'CAD' as CurrencyCode,
SUMM.gross as GrossSpend,
summ.gross * .85 as NetSpend,
'' as NWMFlag,
'' as VPVH,
'' as HouseholdAvgRating,
'' as CPM,
'' as EstimatedImpressions,
'' as EstimatedGRPs,
'' as ActualImpressions,
'' as ActualGRPs,
'' as GenericField1,
'' as GenericField2,
'' as GenericField3,
'' as GenericField4,
'' as GenericField5,
'' as GenericField6
from mediao0.dbo.PPSBUY UNIT,
mediao0.dbo.PPSBUYSUMMARY SUMM,
mediao0.dbo.PPSCLIENT client,
mediao0.dbo.PPSMEDIA media,
mediao0.dbo.PPSPRODUCT product,
mediao0.dbo.PPSPUB PUB
WHERE UNIT.AGENCY = SUMM.AGENCY
AND UNIT.media = SUMM.media
and UNIT.client = SUMM.client
AND UNIT.serial = SUMM.SERIAL
and unit.PRODUCT = summ.PRODUCT
and summ.ISBUYLINETOTAL = 'y'
and unit.agency = client.AGENCY
and unit.Media = client.MEDIA
and unit.Client = client.CLIENT
and unit.agency = media.agency
and unit.media = media.media
and unit.agency = product.agency
and unit.media = product.media
and unit.client = product.client
and unit.product = product.product
and unit.agency = PUB.agency
and unit.media = PUB.media
and unit.pubnumber = PUB.pubnumber 
and unit.pubzone = pub.pubzone
and unit.PUBEDITION = pub.PUBEDITION
and unit.ISDELETED = 'n'
and unit.ISTEST = 'n'
and convert(varchar(10), unit.INSERTIONDATE,120) &gt;= @monthfrom;
"                               
                />
</Query_this>
```

**.ps1 script**

```
$cfgFile = ".\CASMGSTD (3).xml"
$root = "Query_this"
$cfg = [xml] ( gc $cfgFile )



$datestr = Get-Date -format  yyyyMMdd
$startdate =[datetime]::today.Addmonths(-13)

$Date="'"+$startdate.tostring()+"'"
$startdatestr= '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $startdate


$SqlServer = $cfg.$root.SQL.Server
$User= $cfg.$root.SQL.User
$PWD =  $cfg.$root.SQL.PWD
$FTPUser = $cfg.$root.SQL.FTPu
$FTPpw = $cfg.$root.SQL.FTPpw
$Database = $cfg.$root.SQL.DataBase
$FileLocation = $cfg.$root.SQL.FileLocation
$SQLQuery = $cfg.$root.SQL.SQLQuery
$SQLQuery = $SQLQuery.replace("@monthfrom",$monthfrom)
$File = "CA_DDS_A_"+$startdatestr+"_"+$datestr+"_"+$datestr+".txt"
$FileName = $FileLocation+$File


$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($FileName)

function Run-Query()
{
                param (
                $SqlQuery,
                $SqlServer,
                $SqlCatalog, 
                $SqlUser,
                $SqlPass
                )

                if ($SqlUser)
                {
                                $SqlConnString = "Server=$SqlServer;Database=$SqlCatalog;user=$SqlUser;password=$SqlPass"
                } else 
                {
                                $SqlConnString = "Server=$SqlServer;Database=$SqlCatalog;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
                }


                $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $SqlConnString

                $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
                $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
                $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
                $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout= 0

                $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
                $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

                $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
                $a = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

                $SqlConnection.Close()

                #$DataSet.Tables | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Rows
                return ,$DataSet.Tables[0]

}


$dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable
$dt = Run-Query -SqlQuery $SQLQuery -SqlServer $SqlServer -SqlCatalog $Database -SqlUser $User -SqlPass $PWD

##$dt | export-csv .\$FileName -notypeinformation 
$columns =@()
foreach ($col in $dt.columns)
{
##$col | GET-member 
 $columns = $columns + $col.ColumnName
}
$header = [string]::join("`t",$columns)
##Write-Output  $header
$writer.writeline($header)

foreach ($row in $dt.rows)
{
$data = @()
foreach ($col in $dt.columns)
{
if([DBNULL]::Value -eq $row[$col]) 
 { $point ="NULL"} 
 ELSE {$point =$row[$col]}
$data = $data + $point

}
$line =  [string]::join("`t",$data)
$writer.writeline($line)
##Write-Output  $line
}

$writer.Close()
$ftp = "ftp://@ftp.vivakiondemand.com/rootdir/$File"
$ftp
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($FTPuser,$FTPpw)
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

"Uploading $File..."

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $FileName)
```

Comment: What do you do with `SQLQuery`? Is it a variable being passed to an instance of `SqlCommand`?

Comment: Yes here is the .ps1 script

Comment: $SQLQuery = $cfg.$root.SQL.SQLQuery

Comment: $SQLQuery = $SQLQuery.replace("@monthfrom",$monthfrom)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional code in your comments, I think the best solution is to replace the use of a local variable in your SQL with a parameterized query. As you described, you are doing a string replacement to swap the value of @monthfrom with the value of a PowerShell variable. While this works, it is not a good or safe approach.

There are several changes required to your code to fix this. First off, remove the following lines from your SQL query. You do not need to declare the local variable, we are going to use a query parameter in its place.

```
Declare @monthfrom varchar
select @monthfrom = CAST(REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(mm,-36,GETDATE()), 120),'-','') AS int)FROM [mediao0].[dbo].[SPSBUYLINESPOT]
```

Then, remove this line from your PS1 file:

```
$SQLQuery = $SQLQuery.replace("@monthfrom",$monthfrom)
```

Then add these lines to your PS1 file after the code where you set the command timeout:

```
$SqlCmd.CommandType = Text
$SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monthfrom", $monthfrom)
```

This will allow for the value of `$monthno` to be passed along with your query to the server for execution.

Comment: Rather than pasting code into comments, can you edit your original question to include the relevant PowerShell code?

Comment: I have added the .ps1 code to the above description

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I did make the updates you suggested but did encounter this error: "TEXT : The term 'TEXT' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again."  Any idea o what I should change Text too ?